# Google Sheets, how to subtract one array from another?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I've got two arrays, and I want to subtract array2 from the other array1 to form sorted result array. Wondering if it's even possible. I've tried to search everywhere, but haven't found the solution that I know would know how to implement.

```
array1
NAME  DATA1   DATA2   DATA3
MATT    6       2       4
ROBERT  3       2       1
JAKE    2       2       0
PETER   3       1       2
CHARLES 3       1       2
```

```
array2
NAME  DATA1   DATA2   DATA3
MATT    6       2       4
JAKE    2       2       0
ROBERT  2       2       0
CHARLES 2       0       2
```

```
result array
NAME  DATA1   DATA2   DATA3
PETER   3       1       2
CHARLES 1       1       0
ROBERT  1       0       1
MATT    0       0       0
JAKE    0       0       0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({A1:D1; QUERY(QUERY({A2:D6; IFERROR(A9:D12*-1, A9:D12)},
 "select Col1,sum(Col2),sum(Col3),sum(Col4) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1"), 
 "offset 1", 0)})
```

[image: 0]

---

[image: 0]

Comment: Hey, this works great. I was wondering if there was a way to eliminate the rows with 0 on DATA1 from the result?

Comment: sure: `=ARRAYFORMULA({A1:D1; QUERY(QUERY(QUERY({A2:D6; IFERROR(A9:D12*-1, A9:D12)},
 "select Col1,sum(Col2),sum(Col3),sum(Col4) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1"), 
 "offset 1", 0), "where Col2>0", 0)})`